# Devise with Associated Record validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

## My background

I <s>am</s>/was a PHP developper.  Have been for 15 years.  Ruby is new to me (My new challenge)!

## Current Setup

I am using Devise with a User model.
Rails: 3.2.1
Devise: 2.1.2

## Use Case

When the user registers (going thru Devise controller), I want to create the User record but also a Foo record automatically. I created an after_create which handles the creation of the Foo record.

```ruby
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :make_foo

  def make_foo
    Foo.create(
      :name => name,
      :user_id => id
    )
  end

end

Class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

end
```

## Symptoms

I had a problem where when the Foo record was not being created (validation for example), then the User record was still created (I did not want that).  I added a Raise Exception in after_create which rolls back the User creation.
However, I would prefer some nice error handling rather than Exception being throwed.  Right now I get a 500 Error page with that Exception.
I would prefer that the form can be shown again with the reason(s) of the failure.

```ruby
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :make_foo

  def make_foo
    foo = Foo.create(
      :name => name,
      :user_id => id
    )
    if !foo.valid?
      raise Exception.new('Foo creation failed.')
    end
  end

end
```

## Plea for help

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the Devise Resitrations Controller and putting a begin...rescue...end inside the create method.

```ruby
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "my_devise/registrations" }

# app/controllers/my_devise/registrations_controller.rb
class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    begin
      super
    rescue Exception
      self.resource.errors[:base] << "My error message here"
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raising an exception you can redirect back to same page with setting flash message in

```
  if !foo.valid?
```

block like this

```
 flash[:error] = 'error msg'
```

and redirect using

```
 session[:return_to] = request.referer
 redirect_to session[:return_to]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  Maybe it was not clear but the code that creates the Foo record is not in a controller but in a Model. It is not good to put Session and redirection and flash logic inside a model.  It normally goes inside a controller.  The controller is not mine but Devise's controller.  I hope that helps clarify my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Rails3: Devise User has_one relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400363/rails3-devise-user-has-one-relationship) to see if better modelling can make the problem easier.

The way you are modelling user.rb now, is indeed such that a User *may* exist without Foo (which *must* belong to a User however), so it just calls `:make_foo` as an `after_create` callback with no other guarantees whatsoever.

Comment: Looks promissing.  In my case however, my Foo(Team) is polymorphic because a Foo can belong to something else than a User record.  That means I am not sure this applies in my case but I will look.  Thanks,